# Combining results in Angular

Tags: angular, list, service

I have (in Angular 4) a list of product (say that each product has an ID and a Description) that is returned by a service as well as a customer basket with the product ID as well as the purchase date. I would like to display the list of products (ID, Description) with, for the products that are in the customer's basket, the description in bold as well as the purchase date. So this would look like (for example) :
1 - Shoes
2 - Wine
**3- Washing machine - 29.01.19**
4 - Magazine

What is the best approch to this ? Shall I create this "augmented list" of products in TypeScript or is there a way to use the Angular directives ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you show us what you have? Any code.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your specific implementation, I would do something like this:

```html
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let product in products" [ngClass]="{ 'bold' : inCart( product ) }" />
</ul>
```

And then in your component:

```js
inCart( product : any ) : boolean {
    return this.cart.includes( product ); 
}
```

And then in the CSS:

```css
.bold {
    text-style: bold;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: No worries - if this works for you, go ahead and mark this as the answer.